# Caps Locks can't be remapping via AutoHotKey in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, autohotkey

I have the following AHK file running to remap the Caps Locks to control.

```
+Capslock::Capslock ; make shift+Caps-Lock the Caps Lock toggle
 Capslock::Control ; make Caps Lock the control button
```

It works well on other applications like Atom, Chrome, Evernote, and ect. But only has problem with Visual Studio 2013. The Caps Locks still function as caps locks. Even worth, if I accidentally pressed Caps Locks in Visual Studio and close it, I have to reopen Visual Studio and press Caps Locks again to cancel.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: It's possible VS goes a more native route to the keyboard.

Comment: @PaulStelian Possibly, because on the software provided with keyboard, I have disabled the caps locks. The caps locks should not function at all.

Comment: Try [#InstallKeybdHook](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallKeybdHook.htm).

Comment: Thanks @PaulStelian problem solved.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Run AHK as administrator, because I ran the Visual Studio 2013 in admin mode. Then if any application run as administrator, the AHK should run the same, otherwise will be malfunction.

Thanks for Paul Stelian and wOxxOm.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio seems to install some kind of keyboard handler, but I've found that simply (re-)loading my AHK after starting VS brings back my mappings. Presumably, there is some table that VS and AHK are both writing to.

There is a Reload item on the AHK tray icon's context menu.

Also, as there are other situations that will cause CapsLock to be toggled against your wishes, you probably want to either add a mapping to toggle it back (the documentation uses `+Capslock::Capslock` as an example), or else add `SetCapslockState, AlwaysOff` if you never care about using it.